# Set whole image as wallpaper irrespective of its size in android?

Tags: android, image, wallpaper

I am developing an application in android in which i am previewing some images to the user.
The user can choose the image if it wants to set it as its phone background wallpaper.

The problem i am getting is if my image is too big some part of the image cuts down.
So, how can i set whole image as background irrespective of its size??

The code i am using for wallpaper is

```
     WallpaperManager m=WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
             try {
                m.setBitmap(bmap);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) , it really helped me with a similar problem and also improved the performance of my application :)

Answer (score 0):

Add checking for image size and reduce it if needed.

Following code resizes image by defined scale:

```
        float scale = 0.5f;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(oldBitmap, 0, 0, oldBitmap.getWidth(), oldBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: hi tried your code but it is giving exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits